# Sacar los 2 porcentajes mas altos dentro de un array bidimensional

Tags: c

verán, hice un arreglo bidimensional de unas mesas de votaciones, todo me va genial o eso creo, el detalle esta que en el momento que ninguno de los candidatos pase del 50% de las votaciones, se tendrán que sacar los 2 porcentajes mas altos, me da el primer porcentaje mas alto, pero el segundo no me lo muestra, que solución puedo darle?, como podran notar, intente hacer un `while` para que al momento de que encuentre el primer porcentaje mas alto, vuelva al bucle y encuentre al segundo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MESAS 4
#define CANDIDATOS 5


int main(void)
{
    int votos[MESAS][CANDIDATOS],suma,op, promedio_base[5], candidato, mesa, guarda_candidato_mayor;
    float total_votos=0, promedio_mayor, promedio_menor;
    
    for(mesa=0;mesa!=MESAS;mesa++)
    {
        for (candidato=0; candidato!=CANDIDATOS;    ++candidato)
        {
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad de votos para el candidato [%d] en la mesa #%d: ",mesa+1,candidato+1);
            do
            {
                scanf("%d",&votos[mesa][candidato]);
            } while(!(votos[mesa][candidato]>=1) && (votos[mesa][candidato]<=100));
            
            total_votos += votos[mesa][candidato];
        }
        system("cls");
    }
    
    
    
    for ( candidato=0;  candidato!=CANDIDATOS;  ++candidato)
    {
        //printf("\t\t Matriz de la Mesa de elecciones %d\n\n",mesa+1);
        suma=0;
        for (mesa=0;    mesa!=MESAS;    ++mesa)
        {
            printf("En la mesa [%d], el candidato [%d] tiene ==> %d votos\n",mesa+1,candidato+1,votos[mesa][candidato]);
            suma+=votos[mesa][candidato];
        }
        promedio_base[candidato]=suma;
        printf("Suma de los votos es: %d\n", suma);
        printf("Con un promedio de votos de: %.2f%\n\n", 100 * suma / total_votos);
    }
    
    promedio_mayor=promedio_menor=promedio_base[0];
    
    for(candidato=1; candidato<MESAS    ; ++candidato)
    {
        if(promedio_base[candidato]>promedio_base[candidato-1])
        {
            promedio_mayor=promedio_base[candidato];
            guarda_candidato_mayor=candidato;
        }
        else if(promedio_base[candidato-1]<promedio_base[candidato])
        {
            promedio_menor=promedio_base[candidato];
        }
    }
    if((promedio_mayor/total_votos)*100 > 50)
    {
        printf("\n   El candidato ganador de las elecciones es %d: %lf  \n",guarda_candidato_mayor, (promedio_mayor/total_votos)*100);
    }
    else if((promedio_mayor/total_votos)*100 <=50)
        {
        int contador=1,mayor=0,segundo=0;
        float operacion=0;
        printf("\n Ningun candidato supero el 50% \n",guarda_candidato_mayor+1);
        while (contador>=100)
        {
            contador+=1;
            if (operacion>mayor)
            {
                segundo=mayor;
                mayor=operacion;
            }
            else if (operacion>segundo)
            {
                segundo=operacion;
            }
        }
        printf("candidato mayor: %.2f , segundo candidato mayor: %.2f \n"),mayor,segundo;
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he revisado todo tu código, te sugiero que uses variables en inglés y sigas una guía de estilo para codear (como este por ejemplo https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html).

Yendo al problema que consultas, si revisamos el bloque de código en cuestión:

```
    int contador=1,mayor=0,segundo=0;
    float operacion=0;
    printf("\n Ningun candidato supero el 50% \n",guarda_candidato_mayor+1);
    while (contador>=100)
    {
        contador+=1;
        if (operacion>mayor)
        {
            segundo=mayor;
            mayor=operacion;
        }
        else if (operacion>segundo)
        {
            segundo=operacion;
        }
    }
    printf("candidato mayor: %.2f , segundo candidato mayor: %.2f \n"),mayor,segundo;
```

fíjate que nunca entras al `while` ya que no se cumple la condición, seguro que quisite poner `<= 100`. Otro problema es que tu variable `operacion` debería ser un arreglo con los votos por cada candidato.